# How to tell conda init location of .zshrc?

Tags: anaconda, zsh, dotfiles

I'm trying to install miniconda automatically in my setup script. The issue is, I have my .zshrc in ~/.config/zsh/ and when I run

```
eval "${XDG_DATA_HOME}/miniconda/bin/conda init zsh"
```

it creates new .zshrc in my home.

How could I tell the conda init where my .zshrc is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Known Bug with Imminent Fix

This is a known issue and a fix has been [merged into **master** branch](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/10413), but is not yet released. The fix assumes that the `ZDOTDIR` environment variable defines where to find the `.zshrc` file. If one didn't have it defined, then the fix would be

```bash
ZDOTDIR=~/.config/zsh conda init zsh
```

However, that will have to wait until the next release.

#### Temporary Workaround

In the meantime you can just manually copy the code it added to `~/.zshrc` and append it to yours. Or if you are super concerned about Conda running it, you could run this script in the Conda **base** Python

**File: init_zsh.py**

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
from conda.core.initialize import init_sh_user
from conda.base.context import context
from conda.common.path import expand

init_sh_user(expand("$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc"), context.conda_prefix, "zsh")
```

which for you would be something like

```bash
eval "${XDG_DATA_HOME}/miniconda/bin/python init_zsh.py"
```

assuming `ZDOTDIR` is defined.